# Ordenas Array de Mayor a Menor en JAVA

Tags: array, java-8, consola, ordenamiento

tengo un array tipo LONG y el usario es quien ingresa los valores.

y quiera ordenar los datos de mayor a menor.

pdt: los valores que guardan en 0 son valores menores a 1Millon, el resto son mayores.

[image: Array]

Comment: ¿Podrías indicar el código que has realizado por favor? De esta manera podríamos ver en que punto te encuentras atascado y evitamos preguntas de "hacer la tarea" sea o no el caso.

Answer (score 1):

La forma mas sencilla de hacerlo es con el algoritmo de ordenamiento de burbuja.

```
static void burbuja(int arreglo[])
{
    for(int i = 0; i < arreglo.length - 1; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < arreglo.length - 1; j++)
        {
            if (arreglo[j] < arreglo[j + 1])
            {
                int tmp = arreglo[j+1];
                arreglo[j+1] = arreglo[j];
                arreglo[j] = tmp;
            }
        }
    }
    for(int i = 0;i < arreglo.length; i++)
    {
        System.out.print(arreglo[i]+"\n");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Una solución rápida es que en lugar de usar un array estático, utilices el tipo ArrayList porque puedes utilizar la función sort de java.utils.Collections. Quedaría así

```
ArrayList<Long> al = new ArrayList<Long>();

// Aquí rellena el arrayList

//Usamos Collections.reveseOrder() para que ordene de mayor a menor,
//ya que por defecto lo hace al revés
Collections.sort(al, Collections.reverseOrder());
```

Puedes leer más sobre el uso de Collections.sort() aquí: 
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/collections-sort-java-examples/

Como recomienda ordago, puedes pasar tu array a arrayList usando:

```
List <Long> al = new ArrayList<Long>();
Collections.addAll(list1, array);
```

aquí se explican además otras forma: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/Conversion-of-Array-To-ArrayList-in-Java

puedes volver a los arrays simples con toArray():

```
Long[] array = al.toArray();
```

como se explica aquí:
https://howtodoinjava.com/java/collections/arraylist/convert-arraylist-to-array/

Comment: Teniendo en cuenta que OP está trabajando con arrays y no con listas, esta respuesta se podría mejorar indicando como convertir el array en la lista y después como convertir la lista ya ordenada en un array nuevamente.